# Cleaning up sublimetext tags, cannot create synomyn due to variation proportions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently stackoverflow.com has three tags

- sublimetext
- sublimetext2
- sublimetext3

I guess the reason for this is that the text editor *Sublime Text* become to known as *Sublime Text 2* due to wildfire-like spread of this particular version. However, the editor itself is the same product regardless of the version number. Answers for questions apply for different versions. There are sometimes minor differences, but I believe this does not justify having the version number, as having one in the tag name is rare (Internet Explorer tags being notably the exception because of the un-upgradeability of this well-known legacy browser).

However, one cannot suggest merging all tags to sublimetext due to tag proportions:

[image: Failed to propose synonym]

What would be the correct community procecude to discuss and possibly clean up the situation?

Comment: Don't synonymize version numbers. The version number may be relevant, and probably is.

Comment: I am afraid for the most questions I have seen, it is not. For some question it is, but mostly newcomers cannot justify when it is significant or not.

Comment: Even so, it's best to keep version numbers separated. The fact of the matter is, `sublimetext` and `sublimetext2` are _not_ synonyms, even if people incorrectly use them to mean the same thing.